# Replacing arrays in a loop in PHP, performance issue

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

what I do is

1. query (count) of rows from DB
2. replace strings in them
3. write it in .csv

When 150 rows are selected in the first step, around 20sec. are needed to finish the script (csv is ready). If I bypass the second step, nothing replaces, the export is ready for ~2sec.

To replace I defined two not associative arrays: array $replace and array $rwith each with 30 elements.
Then:

```
str_ireplace($replace, $rwith, $value);
```

Probably str_replace (case sensitive) will speed the things up a little, but my goal is under 5s. What can you suggest to optimize this?

Comment: 20 ***seconds*** to replace 150 strings? What, are they 100MB each?

Comment: 150rows by 30 strings. Most of the are 5-10 characters, and 3 of them more than 100 characters

Comment: im wondering if you should try the replacing in your SQL query directly, in fact you could even select into outfile and skip PHP completely

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: Despite the fat query, it runs fast when I comment out the str_replace and str_irepalce. http://pastebin.com/VghFG3ig